# Order By not working when using JSON_ARRAYAGG

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle19c

If I do something like:

```
SELECT name
FROM customers
ORDER BY name
```

They come out in alphabetical order.

But if I do:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(name)
FROM customers
ORDER BY name
```

they come out in the same order every time, but its not alphabetical

Is this a bug, or do I need to do something different?

Comment: Read the manual?  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAYAGG.html#GUID-6D56077D-78DE-4CC0-9498-225DDC42E054 *(It's answered in both the syntax tree and the examples at the end of the page.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ORDER BY` needs to be within the `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function.

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(name ORDER BY name)
FROM customers
```

Having the `ORDER BY` within the `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function sorts the values within the JSON array. Having the `ORDER BY` at the end of your query sorts the order the rows are returned.